# How come variable get's assigned to another array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to walk through a sorted array and count the duplicates to create a new summary-array.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < newCart.length; i++) {
        //if new item.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newCart[i - 1]))
        if ( JSON.stringify(newCart[i - 1]) !==  JSON.stringify(newCart[i])) {
            //add to new displayed items in cart
            results.push(newCart[i]);
            results[results.length - 1].count = 1
        }else{
            console.log('second')
            //add one to the count.
            results[results.length - 1].count++;
        }
    }
```

When I'm looping through this with three items, I get the following output:

```
undefined
{"id":1,"name":"Skateboard","price":1299,"currency":"SEK","image":"/static/img/products/1.jpg","thumbnail":"/static/img/products/1-t.jpg","description":"This board is the boss!","count":1} main.js:47
{"id":1,"name":"Skateboard","price":1299,"currency":"SEK","image":"/static/img/products/1.jpg","thumbnail":"/static/img/products/1-t.jpg","description":"This board is the boss!","count":1}
```

How is it possible that the count variable ends up in the newCart-array?

Comment: You cannot do resulst[].count ....

Comment: why can't I do that?

Comment: is that correct way for adding property in array property?? We cannot add property to property of array...

Comment: I'm not pro in js but guessing...

Comment: Okay... I'm not sure I follow, what should I do instead? And why does it end up in the newCart array?

Comment: There is no `count` property in javascript I am guessing you need the `.length`

Comment: @HTTP Um, yeah! OP might be trying to use that, but incrementing with, it's confusing to me... and I think OP needs to set a variable and then increment in there..

Comment: are you trying to reset your counter value?

Comment: @HTTP, no I try to increase the count by one for each idenctical item.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do `results.push(newCart[i])` it actually puts your cart object into the array, and then you access that `newCart[i]` object and add count to that `newCart[i]` object with `results[results.length-1].count=1`;

Comment: Can I make it not put the cart object in, but rather create a copy of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Could not let this go, since I know I have done similar things in the past. In the question linked above they are actually trying to clone an object without the values. To do what you want to do a simple: `results.push(Object.create(newCart[i]))`

Comment: It only works in IE9 and newer though (and Chrome, and FF and Safari of course). But it is possible to implement for all brosers, see here for that if neccessary (http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)